# Unsure why code isn't working

Tags: java

I am unsure why my code is not working:

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
  if(isBirthday=true){
    speed = speed - 5;
   }
  if(speed<=60){
    return 0;
  }
  if(speed>=81){
    return 2;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

The question is:

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:

```
if (isBirthday = true) {
```

It should be:

```
if (isBirthday == true) {
```

We use *two* equal signs for comparison, otherwise you're just assigning a `true` value to the variable, making it always true. We can go even further and simplify the expression like this:

```
if (isBirthday) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an assignment operator here =, where you should be using an == operator for comparison. So it should be

```
if(isBirthday==true){
    speed = speed - 5;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have a typo here:

```
if(isBirthday=true){
```

this is setting the variable to `true` instead of checking its value

`if(isBirthday==true){` is what you are looking for

and in almost all languages is better when you write

```
if(isBirthday){ for checking if true 
if(!isBirthday){ for checking if false
```

instead